# Conditions for a Euclidean domain to be a field or a polynomial ring over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-domain

I am having trouble proving the following.

> Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain with degree function $\delta,$ i.e., $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)\delta(b)$ for all $a,b\in R-\{0\}$ and $\delta(a+b)\leq\textrm{max}(\delta(a),\delta(b))$. Show that $R$ is a field or that $R=F[x],$ where $F$ is a field.

Comment: Please show us your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted.For future reference, I would request you to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) page which will help you familiarize yourself with asking questions on this website. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, it's the first time I post here and my native language is not English. But the next time I'll follow your instructions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE by the way and thanks for trying to actively learn how to ask while adhering to the guidelines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is $\delta(xy)=\delta(x)+\delta(y)$.

Let $F=\{x:\delta(x)=0\}$. We will prove that  $F$ is a field.

Let $x,y\in F$, then: $ \delta(xy)=\delta(x)+\delta(y)=0, \delta(x+y)\leq \text{max}(\delta(x),\delta(y))=0$, so $x+y,xy \in F$.

$1=ax+r,\delta(r)<\delta(x)=0$, or $r=0$ implies $r=0$ since  $\delta(r)$ is not negative. $1=ax$ implies that $a=a^2x$ and $\delta(a)=\delta(a^2)\delta(x)=0$ implies that $\delta(a)=0, a\in F$.

If $F=R$, then R is a field, and we are done. Suppose now $F\neq R$, i.e. there exists $u:\delta(u)>0$.

Let $x\in R$, having the smallest positive degree amongst all numbers with positive degree, i.e. $\delta(x)>0$ and $\forall y\in R$, $\delta(y)>0 \Rightarrow \delta(x)\leq\delta(y)$, We will prove that $R=F[x]$.

Proof. Recursive on $\delta(y)$ suppose true for $n$, let $\delta(y)=n+1$, we can write $y=zx+b\delta(b)<\delta(x)$ implies that $\delta(b)=0$ and $b\in F$.
$\delta(zb)=\delta(y-b)\leq \delta(y)$. We deduce that $\delta(zb)=\delta(z)+\delta(b)$ and $\delta(z)<n+1$ we deduce that $z\in F[x]$ and $y\in F[x]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About that, in my list of exercises it was written that way: $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)\delta(b)$ And I realized that you used that in the third paragraph with $a=a^{2}x$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Let $F$ be a field, consider the ring of polynomials $F[X]$ it is an Euclidian domain where $\delta(P)=degree(P)$, $degree(X^2)=degree(X.X)=2\neq degree(X)degree(X)$.

Comment: $2^{\deg(f)}$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Btw, you can adapt the proof by taking $F=\{x:\delta(x)=1\}$. (A good opportunity to fix some typos, and to make clear how you chosen $x$.)

Comment: Does $F$ contain the identity? Wouldn't that require $\delta(1)=1$?